# Is it valid? predicate logic

Tags: logic

I need to say whether an argument is valid and if it is then I need to prove it. My question is whether this argument is valid. Lets denote L(x,y) -> x loves y.

$$\forall x~\Big[\exists y\big[L(y, x) \land \forall z~[L(z, x) \to (y = z)]\big]\Big] \land \exists x~[L(x, x)] \iff \exists x~\Big[\lnot \exists y~\big[L(y, x) \land \lnot(x = y)\big]\Big]$$

I think LHS translates as "There is exactly one person who loves everyone and someone loves themselves".
Then RHS I think is "No one loves someone and no one is not someone".
So does it mean that because equivalence does not have the same meaning so it is invalid?

Answer (score 2):

The premise says that everyone is loved by exactly one person and someone loves themself. The conclusion says that there is someone who is not loved by someone else. So yes, it is valid. (I assume that the "=" separering the LHS and the RHS is supposed to mean "implies".)

How you prove depends on what formal deductive system you work with...

Comment: No, it supposed to be equivalence

Comment: @Augustas: Is it supposed to be an argument with zero premises?

Comment: @Augustas: The RHS can be true while the LHS is false.

Comment: Yes, argument with zero premises

Comment: Just to make sure, So does it mean that equivalence is not valid?

Comment: The *argument* is not valid, because the conclusion is not true in all models

Comment: It would be good if this answer was edited to the result it proposes matches the clarified question.

Answer (score 2):

> $$\forall x~\Big[\exists y\big[L(y, x) \land \forall z~[L(z, x) \to (y = z)]\big]\Big] \land \exists x~[L(x, x)] \iff \exists x~\Big[\lnot \exists y~\big[L(y, x) \land \lnot(x = y)\big]\Big]$$
>
> I think LHS translates as "There is exactly one person who loves everyone and someone loves their self".

Not quite.   It is: "Everyone has exactly one person who loves them, and there is someone who loves their self."

> Then RHS I think is "No one loves someone and no one is not someone".

Not at all.   It is "There is someone not loved by someone who is not their self," or simply: "There is someone not loved by anyone else."

Perhaps easiest read using the dual equivalence: $\exists x~\forall y~[L(y,x)\to (x=y)]$, "There is someone whom only their self may love".

---

Now: Determine if the two sequents are equivalent.  the LHS imply the RHS, and is the LHS implied by the RHS?

Comment: I understand now that RHS does not imply LHS because RHS does not indicate that  everyone has exactly one person who loves them. However, how would I prove it? Is there any strategy to find a counterexample?

Comment: Just that, @Augustas Build a universe where the RHS is satisfied, and add a love triangle so that the LHS is not satisfied.  Or notice that the RHS does not require that person to love themselves, just that nobody else does.